# How to remove duplicates using time difference with linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linqpad, drop-duplicates

I have an IEnumerable of an item class defined like this:

```
class Checkup
{
    public Guid SubjectGuid { get; set; }
    public Guid DoctorGuid { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
}
```

For example I have the following data set:

```
SubjectGuid                          DoctorGuid                           Date
2b9dd19f-9ce4-4a0a-832c-e941f5dc0234 6cfbdc40-d30d-4b49-9f02-ca116bcffee0 03.03.2024 11:04:46.644
2b9dd19f-9ce4-4a0a-832c-e941f5dc0234 6cfbdc40-d30d-4b49-9f02-ca116bcffee0 03.03.2024 11:12:27.369
2b9dd19f-9ce4-4a0a-832c-e941f5dc0234 6cfbdc40-d30d-4b49-9f02-ca116bcffee0 03.03.2024 11:30:36.564
bf4e7572-2328-4b19-9a9e-a67aa2f24fba b8dedde9-a397-4469-9c1b-22af4194f35f 03.03.2024 16:24:46.935
bf4e7572-2328-4b19-9a9e-a67aa2f24fba b8dedde9-a397-4469-9c1b-22af4194f35f 03.03.2024 16:39:27.853
bf4e7572-2328-4b19-9a9e-a67aa2f24fba b8dedde9-a397-4469-9c1b-22af4194f35f 03.03.2024 16:59:27.853
efea799a-c755-4f4f-ad80-8ac63fd35d07 b8e88718-55f0-4700-9900-09e8d440345b 03.03.2024 19:00:00.000
efea799a-c755-4f4f-ad80-8ac63fd35d07 b8e88718-55f0-4700-9900-09e8d440345b 03.03.2024 19:21:00.203
efea799a-c755-4f4f-ad80-8ac63fd35d07 b8e88718-55f0-4700-9900-09e8d440345b 03.03.2024 19:50:33.906
```

And I want to remove duplicates if the difference between the date is less than or equal to twenty minutes, while the SubjectGuid and DoctorGuid are the same.
If there are more than two duplicates, then the element with the most recent date within 20 minutes should remain:

```
SubjectGuid                          DoctorGuid                           Date
2b9dd19f-9ce4-4a0a-832c-e941f5dc0234 6cfbdc40-d30d-4b49-9f02-ca116bcffee0 03.03.2024 11:04:46.644
2b9dd19f-9ce4-4a0a-832c-e941f5dc0234 6cfbdc40-d30d-4b49-9f02-ca116bcffee0 03.03.2024 11:30:36.564
bf4e7572-2328-4b19-9a9e-a67aa2f24fba b8dedde9-a397-4469-9c1b-22af4194f35f 03.03.2024 16:24:46.935
bf4e7572-2328-4b19-9a9e-a67aa2f24fba b8dedde9-a397-4469-9c1b-22af4194f35f 03.03.2024 16:59:27.853
efea799a-c755-4f4f-ad80-8ac63fd35d07 b8e88718-55f0-4700-9900-09e8d440345b 03.03.2024 19:00:00.000
efea799a-c755-4f4f-ad80-8ac63fd35d07 b8e88718-55f0-4700-9900-09e8d440345b 03.03.2024 19:21:00.203
efea799a-c755-4f4f-ad80-8ac63fd35d07 b8e88718-55f0-4700-9900-09e8d440345b 03.03.2024 19:50:33.906
```

Here is the code (LINQPad) with which I tried to get the desired result, but it does not work as I would like:

```
void Main()
{
    var checkups = new List<Checkup>()
    {
        new Checkup { SubjectGuid = Guid.Parse("2b9dd19f-9ce4-4a0a-832c-e941f5dc0234"), DoctorGuid = Guid.Parse("6cfbdc40-d30d-4b49-9f02-ca116bcffee0"), Date = DateTime.Parse("03.03.2024 11:04:46.644") },
        new Checkup { SubjectGuid = Guid.Parse("2b9dd19f-9ce4-4a0a-832c-e941f5dc0234"), DoctorGuid = Guid.Parse("6cfbdc40-d30d-4b49-9f02-ca116bcffee0"), Date = DateTime.Parse("03.03.2024 11:12:27.369") },
        new Checkup { SubjectGuid = Guid.Parse("2b9dd19f-9ce4-4a0a-832c-e941f5dc0234"), DoctorGuid = Guid.Parse("6cfbdc40-d30d-4b49-9f02-ca116bcffee0"), Date = DateTime.Parse("03.03.2024 11:30:36.564") },
        new Checkup { SubjectGuid = Guid.Parse("bf4e7572-2328-4b19-9a9e-a67aa2f24fba"), DoctorGuid = Guid.Parse("b8dedde9-a397-4469-9c1b-22af4194f35f"), Date = DateTime.Parse("03.03.2024 16:24:46.935") },
        new Checkup { SubjectGuid = Guid.Parse("bf4e7572-2328-4b19-9a9e-a67aa2f24fba"), DoctorGuid = Guid.Parse("b8dedde9-a397-4469-9c1b-22af4194f35f"), Date = DateTime.Parse("03.03.2024 16:39:27.853") },
        new Checkup { SubjectGuid = Guid.Parse("bf4e7572-2328-4b19-9a9e-a67aa2f24fba"), DoctorGuid = Guid.Parse("b8dedde9-a397-4469-9c1b-22af4194f35f"), Date = DateTime.Parse("03.03.2024 16:59:27.853") },
        new Checkup { SubjectGuid = Guid.Parse("efea799a-c755-4f4f-ad80-8ac63fd35d07"), DoctorGuid = Guid.Parse("b8e88718-55f0-4700-9900-09e8d440345b"), Date = DateTime.Parse("03.03.2024 19:00:00.000") },
        new Checkup { SubjectGuid = Guid.Parse("efea799a-c755-4f4f-ad80-8ac63fd35d07"), DoctorGuid = Guid.Parse("b8e88718-55f0-4700-9900-09e8d440345b"), Date = DateTime.Parse("03.03.2024 19:21:00.203") },
        new Checkup { SubjectGuid = Guid.Parse("efea799a-c755-4f4f-ad80-8ac63fd35d07"), DoctorGuid = Guid.Parse("b8e88718-55f0-4700-9900-09e8d440345b"), Date = DateTime.Parse("03.03.2024 19:50:33.906") },
    };
    checkups.Dump();

    var checkupsNoDuplicates = checkups
        .GroupBy(c => new
        {
            SubjectGuid = c.SubjectGuid,
            DoctorGuid = c.DoctorGuid,
            Time = c.Date.Ticks / TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20).Ticks
        })
        .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(sg => sg.Date).FirstOrDefault());
    checkupsNoDuplicates.Dump();
}

class Checkup
{
    public Guid SubjectGuid { get; set; }
    public Guid DoctorGuid { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

This code produces this result:

```
SubjectGuid                          DoctorGuid                           Date
2b9dd19f-9ce4-4a0a-832c-e941f5dc0234 6cfbdc40-d30d-4b49-9f02-ca116bcffee0 03.03.2024 11:12:27
2b9dd19f-9ce4-4a0a-832c-e941f5dc0234 6cfbdc40-d30d-4b49-9f02-ca116bcffee0 03.03.2024 11:30:36
bf4e7572-2328-4b19-9a9e-a67aa2f24fba b8dedde9-a397-4469-9c1b-22af4194f35f 03.03.2024 16:39:27
bf4e7572-2328-4b19-9a9e-a67aa2f24fba b8dedde9-a397-4469-9c1b-22af4194f35f 03.03.2024 16:59:27
efea799a-c755-4f4f-ad80-8ac63fd35d07 b8e88718-55f0-4700-9900-09e8d440345b 03.03.2024 19:00:00
efea799a-c755-4f4f-ad80-8ac63fd35d07 b8e88718-55f0-4700-9900-09e8d440345b 03.03.2024 19:21:00
efea799a-c755-4f4f-ad80-8ac63fd35d07 b8e88718-55f0-4700-9900-09e8d440345b 03.03.2024 19:50:33
```

---

And dividing ticks will not work always.
For example ticks division in this code:

```
void Main()
{
    var dt1 = DateTime.Parse("03.01.2024 01:27:44.907");
    Console.WriteLine(dt1.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff"));
    Console.WriteLine(dt1.Ticks / TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20).Ticks);
    
    var dt2 = DateTime.Parse("03.01.2024 01:41:55.088");
    Console.WriteLine(dt2.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff"));
    Console.WriteLine(dt2.Ticks / TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20).Ticks);
}
```

Produces result:

```
01.03.2024 01:27:44.907
53199868
01.03.2024 01:41:55.088
53199869
```

Comment: *if the difference between the date is less than or equal to twenty minutes* I am not sure this is an unambiguous requirement, for example if you have 3items spaced by 15 minutes then you could either keep the first and last or you could keep the middle one.

Comment: @JohnWu good catch! in a general form, it would be better to elaborate as a jagged array of `Checkup`s, then in a second step one can pick whatever is better.

Comment: I am not sure that is enough. The problem is that one removal could affect the validity of a different removal.

Comment: @JohnWu agree. In fact, my suggestion is not to remove any item, but to group in a dedicated array instead. Then. for instance, if keeping the earliest item is fine, you simply get the first cell of the array. Anyway, that deserves a clarification by the OP.

Comment: In general, I’m not sure myself, I’ll ask for more detailed information from the author of the problem. In fact, later dates are needed, this is what I know at the moment.

Comment: I found out what was originally intended. If there are more than two duplicates, then the element with the most recent date within 20 minutes should remain.

Comment: @signum the expected result you show in your post (righe below the input data), is it the expected? because it keeps the first occourrence, not the last. Please, fix the expected result, then I'll fix my code (which actually reproduces what you've written).

Comment: @MarioVernari
I think the example at the moment shows what was excepted. If you process data starting from the end, when the list is sorted in ascending order by Date.

Comment: @signum so what's wrong in my solution, then?

Comment: @MarioVernari nothing, i think your answer is great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage the [Aggregate](https://dev.to/ayodejii/understanding-the-enumerableaggregate-method-in-linq-5dpl), which performs a reduction.

Here we go:

```
List<Checkup> result = checkups
    .OrderBy(c => c.Date)   //sorting
    .Aggregate<Checkup, List<Checkup>>(
        [],
        (accumulate, item) =>
        {
            Checkup? match = accumulate
                .LastOrDefault(c => c.SubjectGuid == item.SubjectGuid && c.DoctorGuid == item.DoctorGuid);

            if (match == null)
            {
                accumulate.Add(item);
            }
            else if ((item.Date - match.Date) > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20))
            {
                accumulate.Add(item);
            }
            return accumulate;
        });
```

There's a first ordering (ascending), which could be optional if the input data are ensured already sorted.

Then, there is the aggregation block.

The `Aggregate` function takes as first argument the initial value of the expected result, which is an empty `List<Checkup>` in our case.

The core function is its second argument, which operates on the "accumulation" and the current item. By iterating, the accumulator represents the current-step result. The function elaborates then the post-step result, which will be the accumulator for the next iteration.

When the iteration is over, the actual result is what the accumulator contains.

What the core does in our case?

1. It finds the last entry of the same (`SubjectGuid`, `DoctorGuid`) pair.
2. If there's not, then adds the current item to the accumuator.
3. If there's one, then checks if enough time (20 mins) have been elapsed, and adds the item if that applies.

Comment: As usual, someone gives a downvote without an explaination. What's wrong with my answer? the result it produces is exactly what the OP described in his/her question.

Answer (score 0):

In your current approach, the issue is because of dividing ticks by TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20).

Ticks might not give the desired result for grouping dates in 20-minute intervals.

Instead, you can use a custom grouping logic (helper method) to achieve the desired result of removing duplicates within a 20-minute window.

Something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var checkups = new List<Checkup>()
    {
        new Checkup { SubjectGuid = Guid.Parse("2b9dd19f-9ce4-4a0a-832c-e941f5dc0234"), DoctorGuid = Guid.Parse("6cfbdc40-d30d-4b49-9f02-ca116bcffee0"), Date = DateTime.Parse("03.03.2024 11:04:46.644") },
        new Checkup { SubjectGuid = Guid.Parse("2b9dd19f-9ce4-4a0a-832c-e941f5dc0234"), DoctorGuid = Guid.Parse("6cfbdc40-d30d-4b49-9f02-ca116bcffee0"), Date = DateTime.Parse("03.03.2024 11:12:27.369") },
        new Checkup { SubjectGuid = Guid.Parse("2b9dd19f-9ce4-4a0a-832c-e941f5dc0234"), DoctorGuid = Guid.Parse("6cfbdc40-d30d-4b49-9f02-ca116bcffee0"), Date = DateTime.Parse("03.03.2024 11:30:36.564") },
        new Checkup { SubjectGuid = Guid.Parse("bf4e7572-2328-4b19-9a9e-a67aa2f24fba"), DoctorGuid = Guid.Parse("b8dedde9-a397-4469-9c1b-22af4194f35f"), Date = DateTime.Parse("03.03.2024 16:24:46.935") },
        new Checkup { SubjectGuid = Guid.Parse("bf4e7572-2328-4b19-9a9e-a67aa2f24fba"), DoctorGuid = Guid.Parse("b8dedde9-a397-4469-9c1b-22af4194f35f"), Date = DateTime.Parse("03.03.2024 16:39:27.853") },
        new Checkup { SubjectGuid = Guid.Parse("bf4e7572-2328-4b19-9a9e-a67aa2f24fba"), DoctorGuid = Guid.Parse("b8dedde9-a397-4469-9c1b-22af4194f35f"), Date = DateTime.Parse("03.03.2024 16:59:27.853") },
        new Checkup { SubjectGuid = Guid.Parse("efea799a-c755-4f4f-ad80-8ac63fd35d07"), DoctorGuid = Guid.Parse("b8e88718-55f0-4700-9900-09e8d440345b"), Date = DateTime.Parse("03.03.2024 19:00:00.000") },
        new Checkup { SubjectGuid = Guid.Parse("efea799a-c755-4f4f-ad80-8ac63fd35d07"), DoctorGuid = Guid.Parse("b8e88718-55f0-4700-9900-09e8d440345b"), Date = DateTime.Parse("03.03.2024 19:21:00.203") },
        new Checkup { SubjectGuid = Guid.Parse("efea799a-c755-4f4f-ad80-8ac63fd35d07"), DoctorGuid = Guid.Parse("b8e88718-55f0-4700-9900-09e8d440345b"), Date = DateTime.Parse("03.03.2024 19:50:33.906") },
    };
    
    var checkupsNoDuplicates = checkups
        .GroupBy(c => new
        {
            SubjectGuid = c.SubjectGuid,
            DoctorGuid = c.DoctorGuid,
            TimeSlot = GetTimeSlot(c.Date)
        })
        .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(sg => sg.Date).First());
    
    foreach(var item in checkupsNoDuplicates)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.SubjectGuid} - {item.DoctorGuid} - {item.Date}");
    }
}

// Helper method to get time slot based on date
private long GetTimeSlot(DateTime date)
{
    // 20 minutes in ticks
    long interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20).Ticks;
    
    // Round the ticks down to the nearest 20-minute interval
    long timeSlot = date.Ticks / interval;
    
    return timeSlot;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this code do exactly the same thing, except that the division has been moved to a separate method, but the result will be the same?

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the requirement, you need the last item (in date/time order) of any grouping of items with the same GUID within a 20-minute span.

To put this a different way, you need the set of all items where there does not exist any item within the next 20 minutes with the same GUIDs.

You can achieve this with `!Any`.

```
    var filteredData = data.Where
    (
        x => !data.Any
        (
            y => y != x
              && y.SubjectGuid == x.SubjectGuid
              && y.DoctorGuid == x.DoctorGuid
              && y.Date < x.Date.AddMinutes(20)
        )
    );
```

Comment: I don't downvote you, but that's not working: the result is empty. Moreover, based on the expected result described by the OP, it should be the first item, not the last. Please, correct you answer.

Comment: still not working. At this point, I must downvote you, because the code is wrong. Sorry, mate.